# C++ program for grading multiple True or False tests

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

#### Problem:

My main problem is that I am having difficulty connecting the function containing arrays to the main function.

The history teacher at your school needs help in grading a **True/False** test. The students’ IDs and test answers are stored in a file. The first entry in the file contains answers to the test in the form:

> TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT

Every other entry in the file is the student ID, followed by a blank, followed by the student’s responses. For example, the entry:

> ABC54301 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT

indicates that the student ID is **ABC54301** and the answer to question `1` is **True**, the answer to question `2` is **False**, and so on. This student did not answer question `9`. The exam has `20` questions, and the class has more than `150` students. Each correct answer is awarded two points, each wrong answer gets one point deducted, and no answer gets zero points. Write a program that processes the test data. The output should be the student’s ID, followed by the answers, followed by the test score, followed by the test grade. Assume the following grade scale:

> 90%–100%, A; 80%–89.99%, B; 70%–79.99%, C; 60%–69.99%, D; and 0%–59.99%, F.

#### Code

```
// Chap9BBProg.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int stux;
char stuGrade;
int correctAnswers(char[], char[]);
char studentGrade(int score);
char ansKey[10];
char stuA[10];
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    inFile.open("TFInput.txt");
    outFile.open("TFOutput.txt");
    double score;
    char grade;
    string key;
    string studentID;
    string stuAnswers;
    getline(inFile, key);
    outFile << "The correct answers are " << key << endl << endl;
    while (getline(inFile, studentID, ' '))
    {
        outFile << studentID << " ";
        getline(inFile, stuAnswers);
        stux = studentGrade(stux);
        outFile << " " << stuAnswers << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
int correctAnswers(char answerKey[], char studentAnswers[])
{
    int i;
    int tempscore;
    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    {
        if (answerKey[i] == studentAnswers[i])
        {
            tempscore += 2;
        }
        else if (studentAnswers[i] == ' ')
        {
            tempscore += 0;
        }
        else
        {
            tempscore -= 1;
        }
    }
    cout << tempscore << endl;
    return tempscore;
}
char studentGrade(int x)
{
    int i;
    double score = 0;
    char grade = ' ';
    score = x / 40.0 * 100;
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        if (score >= 90)
            grade = 'A';
        else if (score < 90 && score > 79)
            grade = 'B';
        else if (score <= 79 && score > 69)
            grade = 'C';
        else if (score <= 69 && score > 60)
            grade = 'D';
        else if (score <= 59)
            grade = 'F';
    }
    return grade;
}
```

Comment: Meant to mention, this is the input information:

Comment: TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF
ABC54102 T FTFTFTTTFTTFTTF TF
DEF56278 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF
ABC42366 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTF   
ABC42586 TTTTFTTT TFTFFFTF

Comment: *My main problem is that I am having difficulty connecting the function containing arrays to the main function.* -- That doesn't focus on what the issue is.  Also, if you're having trouble with some aspect of C++, you should have written a small program, maybe 5 or 6 lines, demonstrating the issue you're having.  Posting your entire assignment is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry, not used to using this website. I am having difficulty transferring the data from the function correctAnswers() to the end of the main function. I also need to print the value for grade. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you loop from 0 to 21 when there are only 20 questions (not 22)?  Another point is that your grade calculations are incorrect.  Try `if (score >= 90) ... else if (score >= 80) ... else ...`  .. and why on earth do you loop from 0 to 29 repeatedly calculating the grade?!

Answer (score 2):

Some minor issues noticed for eg in function correctAnswers(), variable tempscore wasn't initialized and function parameters conflict noticed between char[] and string.

```
int stux;
char stuGrade;
int correctAnswers(string, string);
char studentGrade(int score);
char ansKey[10];
char stuA[10];
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    inFile.open("TFInput.txt");
    outFile.open("TFOutput.txt");
    double score;
    string key;
    string studentID;
    string stuAnswers;
    getline(inFile, key);
    outFile << "The correct answers are " << key << endl << endl;
    while (getline(inFile, studentID, ' '))
    {
        outFile << studentID << " ";
        getline(inFile, stuAnswers);
        score = correctAnswers(key, stuAnswers);  //Changed here
        stuGrade = studentGrade(score);  //Changed here
        outFile << " Score: " << score <<" Grade: " << stuGrade << endl;  //Changed here
    }
    return 0;
}

int correctAnswers(string answerKey, string studentAnswers) //Changed here Array to string
{
    int i;
    int tempscore = 0; //Changed here Initialized to 0
    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)  //Changed 22 to 21 here
    {
        if (answerKey[i] == studentAnswers[i])
        {
            tempscore += 2;
        }
        else if (studentAnswers[i] == ' ')
        {
            tempscore += 0;
        }
        else
        {
            tempscore -= 1;
        }
    }
    cout << tempscore << endl;
    return tempscore;
}

char studentGrade(int x)
{
    int i;
    double score = 0;
    char grade = ' ';
    score = x / 40.0 * 100;

    if (score >= 90)
        grade = 'A';
    else if (score < 90 && score > 79)
        grade = 'B';
    else if (score <= 79 && score > 69)
        grade = 'C';
    else if (score <= 69 && score > 60)
        grade = 'D';
    else if (score <= 59)
        grade = 'F';

    return grade;
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm: I didn't touch studentGrade. Edited. Thanks.